# Plotting of time-series of clinical trials

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, seaborn

I have data from a clinical trial study that looks like this:

```
subject_ID Trial_ID MEASUREMENT_1 MEASUREMENT_2 MEASUREMENT_3... MEASUREMENT_101
1             1         0.13       0.12          0.09              0.23
1             2         0.11       0.13          0.089             0.2
```

How can I plot this data as a timeseries with several trials of one subject in one plot?

I wanted to work with matplotlib and seaborn but any other library is okay as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# wide to long form
df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['subject_ID','Trial_ID'],
              var_name='measurement',value_name='value')

# extract numbers from measurements so they will sort correctly on plot
df2['measurement'] = df2['measurement'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)

# get Seaborn to properly interpret for hue keyword argument
df2['Trial_ID'] = df2['Trial_ID'].astype('category')

sns.lineplot(x='measurement',y='value',hue='Trial_ID',data=df2)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly fine, I slightly changed your solution to 

`df2['measurement'] = df2['measurement'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)`


so it accepts the float values of my different measurement. Since I have 75 thousand rows, I tried to only plot the first n e.g. I tried to do that with
 `df2.iloc[1:8]` but I am only getting NaN values for the measurements. Any idea how to do that in a better way?

Comment: You're very welcome. You can do this: `df3 = df2[~df2['value'].isna()]` to pull out just the non-np.nan values.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you simply use the Pandas library, and loop through the subject_IDs one by one using the pandas.plot()

```
import pandas as pd
my_df = pd.read_csv("clinical_trial_study.csv")
subjects = list(set(list(my_df["Subject_ID"])))
for i in subjects:
    temp_df = my_df[my_df["Subject_ID"] == i]]
    #organise your data however you want here - likely using groupby#
    temp_df.plot()
```